# Convert a table to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam/DataFlow and I am creating a custom function as part of the pipeline. The pipeline gets data from BigQuery (first step). The second step requires a transformation of the PCollection.  This function works well on a CSV - creating a dictionary of dictionaries from the table in a CSV, but I do not know how to do this as part of a pipeline with the data source being a big query table. This transformed data will be fed into another step with another function requiring this format.

```
def preProcess(column):
    column = unidecode(column)
    column = re.sub('  +', ' ', column)
    column = re.sub('\n', ' ', column)
    column = column.strip().strip('"').strip("'").lower().strip()

    if not column:
        column = None
    return column


def readData(filename):
    data_d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            clean_row = [(k, preProcess(v)) for (k, v) in row.items()]
            row_id = int(row['Id'])
            data_d[row_id] = dict(clean_row)

    return data_d
```

Here is an attempt to write a function to do it:

```
def datatransform(source): #source is the PCollection from the readBigQuery step
    headers = {'Column1', 'Column2', Column3'}
    data = {}
    for rows in source:
        row = zip(headers,rows)
        data.append(row)
    return data
```

Input would looks like this:
[image]

And the output should look like this - a dictionary of dictionaries:
[image]

Comment: In `datatransform(source)` function, elaborate what `source` looks like. Also, give a sample of how `data` should look which you are returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's BigQuery IO returns the results of your query as a PCollection of rows as dicts, so you shouldn't have to do much to the data there. To collect all those elements in one dict, you can use a [Combine function](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) to collect them into one large dict. You can then consume that in the following transform as a single-element PCollection or a singleton [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) depending on your use case.